# Parallel Resonance in Ultrasonic Transducers (Langevin)

Tags: power-supply, high-voltage, high-frequency, ultrasound, transducer

I am working on a power-supply for ultrasonic welding machines and want to drive the transducer at its parallel resonance.

The Butterworth-Van Dyke model paramters are : L = 24.73e-3; C = 1.14e-9; Cos = 8.29e-9; R = 10.72;

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fdIEe2.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

I wish to drive it at its parallel resonance. From a bode plot i found the anti-resonance(parallel) frequency to be ~32Khz.
I understand it is the frequency when the impedance of Cos||C and L are equal.

From most literature there seems to be a compensating inductor parallel to the Cos.
But adding the compensating inductor would shift the resonant frequency. I added a parallel inductor with a value of 2.7mH so that it would achieve resonance with the Cos at 32Khz.
But it seems to shift my resonance frequency higher up. (The series resonance is unaffected)

What role should the compensating inductor play in the power supply?
Can you set the parallel frequency by changing the compensating inductor or should it be driven at the frequency without the compensation (ie is the parallel frequency unique or is it tunable by the designer)?

Comment: Are you absolutely sure you don't want to run this at series resonance?

Comment: Yes using series is good when load conditions dont change much. In welding process the force applied by the person would vary hence it is much better using parallel. Btw it is a hand held welder.